# Create Multiple sheet named as in coloumn A and copy rows in them with rules

Tags: excel

I'd like to:

[image: Image that desribe what I would like to do]

- Create and title multiple sheets as listed in column A;
- Copy as many times as listed in column B row 3 and 4 from Sheet_Model to every new created sheet

Is possible to do that in excel??
Thank you!!

Comment: **Short Answer**: Yes **Long Answer**: Yeeeeessssssss

Comment: @MacroMan wrong. Long answer is really Yeeeeesssssssss.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1138853

thank you to mikerickson

```
Sub ManySheets()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SheetNamesRange As Range
    Dim oneSheetNameRow As Range
    Dim variableDataRange As Range, fixedDataRange As Range, oneDataRow As Range

    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_Model")
    With SourceSheet
        Set fixedDataRange = .Range("A1:C2")
        Set variableDataRange = Range(.Range("C3"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_0")
        Set SheetNamesRange = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each oneSheetNameRow In SheetNamesRange.Rows
        On Error GoTo MakeNewSheet
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(oneSheetNameRow.Cells(1, 1).Value)

            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear

            SourceSheet.Range("A1:c2").Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, 1)

            If Val(CStr(oneSheetNameRow.Cells(1, 2).Value)) > 0 Then
                For Each oneDataRow In variableDataRange.Rows
                    oneDataRow.Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(oneSheetNameRow.Cells(1, 2))
                Next oneDataRow
            End If

        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next oneSheetNameRow
Exit Sub
MakeNewSheet:
    If Err = 9 Then
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Worksheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = oneSheetNameRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
        End With
        Resume
    Else
        MsgBox Err & vbCr & Error
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain the answer you are posting.